# How do equipment manufacturers test equipment?

Tags: united-states, legal, fcc

How do manufacturers of ham radio equipment test the devices they sell without violating laws against commercial use of ham radio frequencies?

Comment: Is a transmission in a Faraday cage actually a transmission?

Comment: The answers here are good but I think the question itself is pretty much the same as https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/20351/how-do-businesses-develop-and-test-amateur-radio-products-in-the-us-if-you-canno

Answer (score 2):

Many RF equipment tests can be done using well shielded and tapped dummy loads, programmable signal generators with adjustable attenuators, and/or other suitable laboratory test and measurement equipment.

I test one of my dual port full duplex transceiver kits by running the transmitter output via shielded coax thru a calibrated attenuator back into the receiver, or into an oscilloscope or spectrum analyzer (tinySA) to cross check the test measurements.

Comment: Yes but they have the expensive "toys" that allow them to do this. They also keep them in calibration.

Answer (score 1):

Engineers typically use a mixture of equipment including a [dummy load](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_load), signal generator, [frequency counter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_counter) and [power meter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wattmeter).

**Dummy Load**

A [dummy load](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_load) allows an engineer to simulate an antenna whilst absorbing most if not all of the RF load.

**Frequency Counter**

A [frequency counter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_counter) allows an engineer to measure the frequency and can assist with fine adjustment of the transceiver's transmitter circuits.

**Signal Generator**

A [signal generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_generator) generates a signal that can mimic an incoming transmission allowing receive adjustment and optimisation.

**Power Meter (aka Wattmeter)**

A [power meter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wattmeter) facilitates measurement and fine adjustment of the output power (watts output) of the transmitter.

Of course, there are many other tools and equipment. This reply is designed to be a succinct answer to the question.

P.S. [@kj7rrv](https://ham.stackexchange.com/users/22962/kj7rrv) If this answered your question today, please mark this contribution as the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).